# Failed to remote debugging on using command line `process connect connect://iOSIP:Port`

Tags: ios, xcode, lldb

I'm reading the topic is LLDB and debugserver in iOS Reverse Engineering book and encountering an error in details as below.

All configuration is well.
But when I'm using the lldb of Xcode5 or Xcode6 , the command  `process connect connect:iOSIP:Port` showed up an error as below,

> (lldb) process connect connect://10.18.136.168:1234 Assertion failed:
>   (pointer_byte_size == m_host_arch.GetAddressByteSize()), function
>   GetHostInfo, file
>   /SourceCache/lldb/lldb-300.2.53/source/Plugins/Process/gdb-remote/GDBRemoteCommunicationClient.cpp,
>   line 1266. Abort trap: 6

And when I'm using the lldb of Xcode8 , the command  `process connect connect:iOSIP:Port` showed up an error as below,

> (lldb) process connect connect://10.18.136.168:1234 Process 8147
>   stopped
>   * thread #1, stop reason = signal SIGSTOP
>       frame #0: 0x00000001987ace0c error: memory read failed for 0x1987ace00

Environment:

1. macOS Sierra
2. Xcode 8.3.2
3. Xcode 6.0.1
4. Xcode 5.0.2
5. iOS 8.2 jailbroken

I've tried the lldb of three versions of Xcode using the command line `process connect connect://10.18.136.168:1234`, all are failed.

Answer (score 0):

After a little while, I've found a solution and I want to share it here.

Solution Link: http://bbs.iosre.com/t/failed-to-remote-debugging-on-using-command-line-process-connect-connect-iosip-port/8259/4

The problem is about the architecture of the device. When I thinned `debugserver` using `armv7s` architecture and it failed to attach `process`.

However, there is a webpage shown `pointer_byte_size == m_host_arch.GetAddressByteSize()` in function `GetHostInfo` in linking to https://reviews.llvm.org/file/data/j3cbbw4262e57hrbundw/PHID-FILE-vojdaczcpqpc5h2sl6hl/file .

So I thinned it by using `arm64` to output an new `debugserver`, the command as shown below

> lipo -thin arm64 debugserver -output debugserver
>   codesign -s - --entitlements ent.plist -f debugserver

Finally, it works to my iphone 5, and to debug any app are okay and smoothly.